# What is the correct way to get the total count of a metric in Graphite

Tags: api, graphite, statsd

I am trying to fetch the total number of successful logins using Graphite's render API.

```
http://localhost/render?target=hitcount(stats_counts.login.success,"99years",true)&from=-99years&format=json
```

This query is taking **too long to execute** (~ 30 seconds).

Is this the correct way to fetch the total number ?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on-

1. The amount of data that the API call has to go through to render this query.
2. Granularity- One point per month will be ~30 times faster than a point a day.
3. Physical host specs- While you query use `iostat -x 1` to see if your disk is doing 100% IO.

Comment: OK so that is the reason for the slowness. But what about the query, is it the right way to do it ? I'm new to Graphite

Comment: Yes your method of querying is correct. FYI, if you don't have granularity shifts in those 99years, `summarize()` would work equally well.